# Display list tempate

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to implement the List template feature of Alexa skill kit. However, I am unable to return the response in an appropriate format.

I have implemented the feature using the official documentation. However, I am not getting how to return the response of list template to my custom intent

```
'ListTemplate':function(){

    var title = "This is a sample list";
    var speechOutput = "Showing the sample list";

    var template = {

        "type":"Display.RenderTemplate",
        "template":{
            "type":"ListTemplate1",
            "token":"ListTemplate",
            "title":title,
            "backButton":"VISIBLE",
            "backgroundImage":{
                "contentDescription":"backgroundImage",
                "sources":[
                    {
                        "url":"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/hostel-720.jpg"
                    }]
            },

            "listItems":[{
                "token":"item1",
                "image":{
                    "sources":[{
                        "url":"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/c-v-raman-college-of-engineering-squarelogo-1534916004379+(3).jpg"
                    }],
                    "contentDescription":"first item of list"
                },
                "textContent":{
                    "primaryText":{
                        "type":"PlainText",
                        "text":"primary Text is here"
                    },
                    "secondaryText":{
                        "type":"PlainText",
                        "text":"Secondary text is here"
                    }

                },
            },

            {
                "token":"item2",
                "image":{
                    "sources":[{
                        "url":"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/c-v-raman-college-of-engineering-squarelogo-1534916004379+(3).jpg"

                }],
                "contentDescription":"second item"

            },
            "textContent":{
                "primaryText":{
                    "type":"PlainText",
                    "text":"primary text is here"
                },
                "secondaryText":{
                    "type":"PlainText",
                    "text":"secondary text"
                }
            }
            }
        ]
        }};




    var directives =[ template ];

    //return build_speechlet_response(title,speechOutput,directives, SESSION_LIST);
```

//  function

```
build_speechlet_response(title,speechOutput,directives,phase){

    const response = {
         "version": "1.0",
         "response": {
             "outputSpeech":{
                 "type":"PlainText",
                 "text":"what else would you like to see"

             },
             "card":{
              'type':'Simple',
              'title':title,
              'content':speechOutput
             },
             "directives":directives,
             "shouldEndSession":'False'
         },
         "sessionAttributes":{
             "template":"list_"
         }

     };

    // return response;

         this.emit(':tell',response);


},
```

The response I should get must be a custom list. But I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issues is that `response` is an object. It should be something like `this.emit(':tell', speechOutput)` (where `speechOutput` is a string).

If you want to also send a card it's `this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj)`.

But, since you're trying to use a render template, it would be something like:

```
this.response.speak(speechOutput)
  .cardRenderer(cardTitle, cardContent, cardImage)
  .renderTemplate(template);

this.emit(':responseReady');
```

You can find more info here - https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/tree/1.x

I do notice you're using v1 of the SDK - I would really recommend using v2 as it's a lot more straight forward.

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Can you guide me as to how do i use v2 in place of v1?

Comment: The GitHub repo for v2 has some good documentation. It also has links to some good examples too - depending on what skill you’re building. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#samples

Comment: Sir I installed all the packages from Github docs. But still unable to import it in my lambda function

Comment: Hi. Can you show what you're doing - do you have some code? It seems this is a different question to your original one that I answered though.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried the following code yet the response was not rendered. 

const DisplayListIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'DisplayList';
    },

    handle(handlerInput){
        var title = "This is a sample list";
        var speechOutput = "Showing the sample list";

        var template = {

        type:'Display.RenderTemplate',
        template:{
            type:"ListTemplate1",
            token:"ListTemplate",
            title:'title',
            backButton:"VISIBLE",
            backgroundImage:{
                contentDescription:"backgroundImage",
                sources:[
                    {
                        url:"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/hostel-720.jpg"
                    }]
            },

            listItems:[{
                token:"item1",
                image:{
                    sources:[{
                        url:"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/c-v-raman-college-of-engineering-squarelogo-1534916004379+(3).jpg"
                    }],
                    contentDescription:"first item of list"
                },
                textContent:{
                    primaryText:{
                        type:"PlainText",
                        text:"primary Text is here"
                    },
                    secondaryText:{
                        type:"PlainText",
                        text:"Secondary text is here"
                    }

                },
            },

            {
                token:"item2",
                image:{
                    sources:[{
                        url:"https://democard.s3.amazonaws.com/c-v-raman-college-of-engineering-squarelogo-1534916004379+(3).jpg"

                }],
                contentDescription:"second item"

            },
            textContent:{
                primaryText:{
                    type:"PlainText",
                    text:"primary text is here"
                },
                secondaryText:{
                    type:"PlainText",
                    text:"secondary text"
                }
            }
            }
        ]
        }};

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .addRenderTemplateDirective(template)
        .getResponse();

    }
};
```